The variational derivative of the metric with respect to inverse metric
I have a somewhat naive question. However, consider the functional derivative
$$
\frac{\delta \partial_\mu g_{\alpha \beta}(x)}{\delta g^{\gamma \epsilon}(y)}.
$$
Is it should be
$$
\frac{\delta \partial_\mu g_{\alpha \beta}(x)}{\delta g^{\gamma \epsilon}(y)}= -\frac{1}{2} \partial_\mu\left[[g_{\alpha \gamma}(x) g_{\beta \epsilon}(x)+g_{\alpha \epsilon}(x) g_{\beta \gamma}(x)] \delta(x-y)\right] ,\tag{1}
$$
or
$$
\frac{\delta \partial_\mu g_{\alpha \beta}(x)}{\delta g^{\gamma \epsilon}(y)}= -\frac{1}{2} \left[g_{\alpha \gamma}(x) g_{\beta \epsilon}(x)+g_{\alpha \epsilon}(x) g_{\beta \gamma}(x) \right] \partial_\mu \delta(x-y)~?\tag{2}
$$

Eq. (1) is correct.

The correct expression is (1). The key point is that the derivative $\partial_\mu$ acts on the entire expression within the functional derivative, not just the delta function.
To see this, we start with the definition of the functional derivative:
$$
\delta F[g] = \int d^4y \frac{\delta F[g]}{\delta g^{\gamma \epsilon}(y)} \delta g^{\gamma \epsilon}(y).
$$
In our case, $F[g] = \partial_\mu g_{\alpha \beta}(x)$. We know that the variation of the metric tensor is given by
$$
\delta g_{\alpha \beta}(x) = - \frac{1}{2} (g_{\alpha \gamma}(x) g_{\beta \epsilon}(x) + g_{\alpha \epsilon}(x) g_{\beta \gamma}(x)) \delta g^{\gamma \epsilon}(x).
$$
Therefore, the variation of $\partial_\mu g_{\alpha \beta}(x)$ is
$$
\delta (\partial_\mu g_{\alpha \beta}(x)) = \partial_\mu (\delta g_{\alpha \beta}(x)) = \partial_\mu \left( - \frac{1}{2} (g_{\alpha \gamma}(x) g_{\beta \epsilon}(x) + g_{\alpha \epsilon}(x) g_{\beta \gamma}(x)) \delta g^{\gamma \epsilon}(x) \right).
$$
We can rewrite $\delta g^{\gamma \epsilon}(x)$ as $\int d^4y \delta(x-y) \delta g^{\gamma \epsilon}(y)$.  Substituting this into the above expression, we get
$$
\delta (\partial_\mu g_{\alpha \beta}(x)) = - \frac{1}{2} \partial_\mu \left( \int d^4y (g_{\alpha \gamma}(x) g_{\beta \epsilon}(x) + g_{\alpha \epsilon}(x) g_{\beta \gamma}(x)) \delta(x-y) \delta g^{\gamma \epsilon}(y) \right).
$$
Since $\partial_\mu$ acts on the entire expression, including the metric terms and the delta function, we can move it outside the integral:
$$
\delta (\partial_\mu g_{\alpha \beta}(x)) = - \frac{1}{2} \int d^4y \partial_\mu \left( (g_{\alpha \gamma}(x) g_{\beta \epsilon}(x) + g_{\alpha \epsilon}(x) g_{\beta \gamma}(x)) \delta(x-y) \right) \delta g^{\gamma \epsilon}(y).
$$
Comparing this with the definition of the functional derivative, we obtain
$$
\frac{\delta \partial_\mu g_{\alpha \beta}(x)}{\delta g^{\gamma \epsilon}(y)} = - \frac{1}{2} \partial_\mu \left[ (g_{\alpha \gamma}(x) g_{\beta \epsilon}(x) + g_{\alpha \epsilon}(x) g_{\beta \gamma}(x)) \delta(x-y) \right].
$$
This is precisely expression (1).
The error in expression (2) is that it incorrectly assumes that $\partial_\mu$ only acts on the delta function, neglecting the product rule for derivatives. The derivative must act on the entire product of the metric terms and the delta function.
